# JQuery - Class Changes Not Registered

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am currently in the process of putting together a site for a workout log. Right now, I am creating the page that team admins will use to manage the players on their team. To give you a visual of how the member management bar looks, I am attaching the following photo:

[image: Member Dashboard]

**BACKGROUND/FILES**

After some PHP, the HTML rendered is as follows:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Members</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover table-condensed" id="table1">
          <tr style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <td style="text-align: left;">Matthew Gross</td>
            <td style="text-align: right;"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></a>&emsp;<a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle del-member" member="1"></span></a>&emsp;<a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user admin-member" member="1"></span></a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <td style="text-align: left;">Nud Nud</td>
            <td style="text-align: right;"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></a>&emsp;<a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle del-member" member="3"></span></a>&emsp;<a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user n-admin-member" member="3"></span></a></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Additionally, I have some JQuery and AJAX scripts to handle clicking the icons. In the case of my bug, I am only focusing on the user-icon, which is handled with my AJAX and JQuery, as follows:

```
// AJAX Handler
function sendAjax(req, body)
{
    // Get group data via AJAX to PHP request
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST","manage.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("req="+req+"&body="+body);
}

// Admin Management
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.admin-member').click(function(e) {
        var m_id = $(this).attr('member');
        $(this).toggleClass('admin-member n-admin-member');
        sendAjax("r-ad", m_id);
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.n-admin-member').click(function(e) {
        var m_id = $(this).attr('member');
        $(this).toggleClass('n-admin-member admin-member');
        sendAjax("a-ad", m_id);
    });
});
```

**THE PROBLEM**

For both users, when I first click the user icon, the AJAX successfully runs and their admin bit in the database is changed. In terms of CSS, as you will note in the JQuery code, the class is correctly changed from `n-admin-member` to `admin-member` or vice-versa. On the UI side, this looks like it works 100%. However, if I click on the user icon again in order to change the admin status back, the AJAX is still performing the previous query.

**EXAMPLE**

1. Nud Nud is not an admin (thus his user icon is black).
2. Nud Nud's icon is clicked.
3. JQuery calls the `$('.n-admin-member').click(function(e)` function.
4. Nud Nud is now an admin, and his class has toggled from
   `n-admin-member` to `admin-member` (his icon is now green).
5. Nud Nud's icon is clicked again.
6. JQuery *should* call the `$('.admin-member').click(function(e)`
   function, due to Nud Nud's span's change of class to
   `admin-member`.
7. *INSTEAD* the `$('.n-admin-member').click(function(e)` function is called again.

**SUSPICIONS**

I suspect this is because the JQuery is somehow not recognizing the change in class that was made when the user icon was clicked the first time (and thus it's still running the make admin function, rather than the un-make admin function). Using dev tools, I was able to confirm the class change, but I still think that this change is somehow not being registered in JQuery.

I appreciate any and all insight that you may have! I am sure that this is an easy JQuery fix, but it is escaping me at the moment. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [event delegation](https://api.jquery.com/on/) to resolve this issue, in this case:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#table1').on('click', '.admin-member', function(e) {
        var m_id = $(this).attr('member');
        $(this).toggleClass('admin-member n-admin-member');
        sendAjax("r-ad", m_id);
    });  
    $('#table1').on('click', '.n-admin-member', function(e) {
        var m_id = $(this).attr('member');
        $(this).toggleClass('n-admin-member admin-member');
        sendAjax("a-ad", m_id);
    });
});
```

As the element with that class doesn't originally exist.

Comment: I knew it was something along those lines! Darn DOM modifications... Thank you!